# Не работает парсер на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Не работает парсер, не понимаю в чем проблема, все раньше нормально работало, а сейчас ошибку выдает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "123.py", line 36, in <module>
    parse()
  File "123.py", line 30, in parse
    img = get_image(html)
  File "123.py", line 16, in get_image
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  File "C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 307, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

Вот сам код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-poluavtomaticheskoy-svarki-mig'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}
FILE = 'svarka.csv'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_image(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-products')
    image = []
    for img in image:
        image.append(
            item.find('a', class_='b-products__text').get('href')
            )
    return  image

def parse():
    URL = input('Введите URL: ')
    URL = URL.strip()
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        img = get_image(html)
        print(img)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `BeautifulSoup` нужно передавать строку, байты или файловый объект, а вы передали объект `requests.Response`.

Советую давать правильные имена параметрам и указывать тип параметров и возвращаемых значений в функциях, это не обяжет интерпретатор проверять типы, но поможет IDE и программистам.

Пример:

```
...
def get_html(url, params=None) -> requests.Response:                # <<<<<
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_image(html: bytes):                                         # <<<<<
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-products')
    image = []
    for img in image:
        image.append(
            item.find('a', class_='b-products__text').get('href')
        )
    return  image

def parse():
    URL = input('Введите URL: ')
    URL = URL.strip()
    rs = get_html(URL)                                           # <<<<<
    if rs.status_code == 200:                                    # <<<<<
        img = get_image(rs.content)                              # <<<<<
        print(img)
    else:
        print('Error')
```